# MS bot often getting Send Failed error but the conversation still proceeds

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm developing a chat bot using MS bot framework (v4) and I'm using Direct-line bot channel. Often I'm getting this issue, whenever we ask some question in bot it responds in 2-3 seconds. but the status of the asked question will remains as sending for 20 seconds and then turned as **Send failed. Retry** on retrying also it repeats the same.

When i tried the same in web-chat, it gives the same issue.

[image]

**Please explain me why this is happening and how to fix this issue.**

[image]

**Some Additional information for investigating my issue:**

1) Are you using any middleware?

```
No, I'm not using any middleware
```

2) Where is your bot hosted?

```
BOT hosted in Azure only,
```

3) Please include the surrounding code where the bot sends "Hi!".

```
private async Task ProcessSampleQnAAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            mPrevUserMssg = input;
            _logger.LogInformation("ProcessSampleQnAAsync");
            var metadata = new Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.Metadata();
            var qnaOptions = new QnAMakerOptions();

            metadata.Name = product;
            metadata.Value = release;
            qnaOptions.StrictFilters = new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.Metadata[] { metadata };
            qnaOptions.ScoreThreshold = 0.3F;

             var results =await _botServices.SampleQnA.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext, qnaOptions);
            if (results.Any())
            {

                if (checkval == null)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(results.First().Answer), cancellationToken);
                    await endmessageSuggestedActionsAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Please try with a different phrase"), cancellationToken);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                metadata.Name = "editorial";
                metadata.Value = "chitchat";
                qnaOptions.StrictFilters = new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.Metadata[] { metadata };
                qnaOptions.ScoreThreshold = 0.3F;
                var chitchatresults = await _botServices.SampleQnA.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext, qnaOptions);

                if (chitchatresults.Any())
                {
                    var response = chitchatresults.First().Answer;
                    var answers = response.Split('|');
                    if (answers.Count() > 1)
                    {
                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        int index = rnd.Next(answers.Count());
                        response = answers[index];
                    }
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response), cancellationToken);
                        await endmessageSuggestedActionsAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken); 
                }
                        else { 

                        if (unaswered == 0)
                        {
                            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, I've no answer"), cancellationToken);
                            unaswered = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, I am still unable to find answer."), cancellationToken);
                            unaswered = 0;
                        }

            }
        }
```

4) What is your appId or bot name (I'll look things up on the backed).

c48119d1-8078-4804-bc20-9dead31ea0f7

5) What version of Web Chat are you using?

I'm using the latest version web chat / directline bot channel in my site

Comment: What type of App Service Plan do you have?

Comment: @JeganBaskaran This could be caused by many things. 1) Are you using any middleware? 2) Where is your bot hosted? 3) Please include the surrounding code where the bot sends "Hi!". 4) What is your appId or bot name (I'll look things up on the backed). 5) What version of Web Chat are you using? Please edit answers to this into your question and let me know.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, thanks for replying, I've answered for all the questions you had mentioned with the best of my knowledge, kindly check and let me know if this is sufficient to investigate and help me to fix this issue

Comment: @billoverton, thanks for replying, I'm currently using free service only since I'm still in the development face,

Comment: @JeganBaskaran Backend logs don't show any service interruptions. It looks like there may be something in your bot that isn't allowing the turn to complete (HTTP Response is sent at the end of a turn, regardless of bot messages that occur before then). 1) Are you missing any `return`s anywhere? 2) Is there any code that could be preventing your bot from responding or that might be throwing an error (please edit in any errors)? 3) Are you behind a proxy or firewall that might be preventing the request from finishing?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT,  thank yo so much for checking my issue,  

Following is my answers:

I don't miss any returns in my code, 
There is no code preventing the bot from responding also, i verified them again. 
There is some firewall settings in existence within my project network, and also many users login via VPN and access the bot, but not sure how that will affect this issue,

if this issue is due to the firewall settings of my network, how to fix it ?, definitely, I wont be able to modify the settings, is there any other option to fix this issue.

Comment: @JeganBaskaran I'm not entirely sure the issue is due to a firewall. Can you try deploying [multi-turn-prompt sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt) and seeing if you run into the same issue? If you do, it's the firewall. If you don't, it's your code.